# Java: Iterate inconsistent list object

Tags: java

I'm trying to display array list indexing from a inconstant size of array from an object. How do iterate an arraylist that have inconsistent of size within to prevent IndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Hello b = new Hello();
System.out.println("test 1 =" +b.Apple().get(0));
System.out.println("test 2 =" +b.Apple().get(1));
System.out.println("test 3 =" +b.Apple().get(2));

}
```

Hello.java file which return result of inconsistent index list

```
public ArrayList<Integer> Apple(){
ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();

rs = db.getSM().executeQuery("SELECT a, b, count(*) AS rowCount from table");   
while(rs.next()) {
    values.add(rs.getInt("count"));
}

return values;
```

Expected result

First run, it only have 2 element. so it will print

```
test 1 = 23
test 2 = 13
test 3 = 0
```

Second run, it will have 3 element. so it will print

```
test 1 = 23
test 2 = 10
test 3 = 3
```

Comment: Would you be satisfied, if `test 3 = 0` is not displayed in the first run?

Comment: Is it possible of making it 0 if index 2 not found?

Comment: you should transform `Apple` into a generator

Comment: Usual methods would omit the `test 3 = 0` and use a `for` loop bounded by the list's size, an `Iterator` or `Collection.forEach`

Comment: @Aaron. Do I need to do nested for loop?

Comment: Not at all. I've also forgotten to mention "foreach" loops which are similar to bounded `for` loops without the hassle of managing an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample solutions if you can omit the `test 3 = 0` mention when there are only two elements :

```
for(int index=0; index<yourList.size(); index++) {
    Object element=yourList.get(index);
    // do something with the element (and its index if needed)
}
```

```
for(Object element : yourList) {
    //do something with the element
}
```

```
Iterator<Object> it = yourList.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Object element = it.next();
    //do something with your element
}
```

```
yourList.forEach(element -> /* do something with your element */);
```

Apart from the first solution providing an index, all these solutions are functionally equivalent.

Don't use `Object` as I did for the element type, you should obviously use the type of your elements instead.

To produce your current output the first solution seems the most adequate since it provides an index :

```
ArrayList<Integer> yourList = b.Apple();
for (int index=0; index < yourList.size(); index++) {
    System.out.printf("test %d = %d", index + 1, yourList.get(index));
}
```

(`printf` takes a string template and a list of parameters for this template ; here `%d` represents numbers, the first occurence is replaced by the 1-based index and the second by the list element's value)

---

If you don't want to omit the `test 3 = 0` output, I think [Federico klez Culloca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133203/)'s suggestion to create a generator is best, but since I'm not familiar with them I'll instead provide a solution that adds zeroes to the list until it reaches the target size :

```
ArrayList<Integer> yourList = b.Apple();
int desiredSize=3;
int missingZeroes = desiredSize - yourList.size();
for(int addedZeroes=0; addedZeroes < missingZeroes; addedZeroes++) {
    yourList.add(0);
}
//then proceed with the above List traversal solutions.
```

Comment: Thank you so much =) I got it